# fatal error: X11/Xauth.h: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, cross-compiling

when I cross-compile libxcb it remind me"fatal error: X11/Xauth.h: No such file or directory" then I cross-compile xauth. But it always remind the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same error. But with installation of `libXau`, the error went away.